# Demonstration over a sequences of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Imagine an infinite sequence of complex numbers $w_i$, and another one $z_i$. The next facts are known:

- $\arg(z_i) = \arg(w_i), \forall i \in \mathbb{N}-0$
- $z_i\ne 0, w_i\ne0, \forall i \in \mathbb{N}-0$
- $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} z_i =  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} w_i = 0$
- $|z_i| \ne |z_j|,  \forall i \ne j$ and $|w_i| \ne |w_j|,  \forall i \ne j$
- $\forall i, \exists j \in \mathbb{N} | \arg(z_i) \ne \arg(z_j)$

Can it be proved that the former conditions implies necessarily that  exits a $k \in \mathbb{R}$ such as $z_i= k\cdot w_i \quad \forall i$?

It seems obvious common sense wise but I am struggling to find a formal way to prove it.

Comment: What if we add the further restriction:  $|z_k|=k^\alpha$ and $|w_k|=k^\beta$ where $(\alpha,\beta) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ ? Can it then be concluded that $\alpha = \beta$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and in fact, a counterexample exists with only finitely many of the $z_i$ or $w_i$ nonzero. It's easier to describe as a picture: the sequence $z_i$ forms a "polygon" $0, z_1, z_1 + z_2, \dots$ which closes back in on itself because of the condition that the sum is zero. We want to show that we can change the lengths of some of the sides of this polygon without changing any of the angles a side makes with the sides adjacent to it, without just scaling all of the sides by the same factor. We can do this if any two sides are parallel by just increasing the length of both sides by the same amount.

The various other conditions just imply that this polygon can't be too regular but nevertheless it ought to be possible to draw a counterexample with $6$ sides, I think.

Comment: It is very nice visual way to see it. Thanks!